# Ajax-update a component in h:column header from inside a cell

Tags: jsf, columnheader, ajax-update

I have datatable with checkboxes on each row and a single checkbox on table column to check/uncheck all.

```
<h:dataTable id="datatable1">
 <h:column headerClass="center-checkbox"> 
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.tbl.checkAll}" id="checkAllSelector">
                                    <f:ajax render="datatable1 "/>
                                </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox  value="#{bean.tbl.checked[r]}">
                                <f:ajax render="checkAllSelector"/>
                            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                        </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

I want to re-render checkAllSelector on every checkbox click in table row but

```
<f:ajax render="checkAllSelector"/>
```

is transalated to this (for each row)

```
onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange',0,'datatable1-1-checkAllSelector')"
onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange',0,'datatable1-2-checkAllSelector')"
onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange',0,'datatable1-3-checkAllSelector')"
```

and it should be

```
onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange',0,'datatable1-checkAllSelector')"
onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange',0,'datatable1-checkAllSelector')"
onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange',0,'datatable1-checkAllSelector')
```

How to avoid preapending this id of each checkbox 
The form tag has prependId="false"

Comment: If i put a div arount h:dataTable <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="tblContainer" > <h:dataTable id="datatable1"></h:dataTable></h:panelGroup> and point ajax to this div  <f:ajax render="tblContainer"/> everything works fine . Ajax action is translated to onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange',0,'tblContainer')"